# Python / Elaphe generates broken barcodes

Tags: python, barcode, elaphe

I am trying to generate code128 barcodes using Python/Elaphe, which is based on Barcode Writer In Pure Postscript (BWIPP). Strangely, the barcodes generated by Elaphe don't match the ones generated by BWIPP and do not conform to code 128 standard.

In particular, I tried a simple example, the generation of a barcode for the letter 'A' (capital A):

```
from elaphe import barcode 
b = barcode('code128', 'A') 
b.show()
```

That works just fine, but the generated barcode is missing the right part. It is 35 pixels wide, where it should be 46. The left part of the barcode matches the one generated by BWIPP and every other code128 generator - it's only the right section that is missing.

Anyone know what's wrong?

(Using elaphe 0.6.0 with python 2.7.10 on Kubuntu 15.10)

Comment: Show us both images.

Comment: [link]http://imgur.com/a/DlFKP

Answer (score 0):

See this bug report:
https://bitbucket.org/whosaysni/elaphe/issues/84/code-128-generation-produces-unreadable

It seems that this bug is fixed in the current source version, also the bug is still marked as new.
The the patch which fixed this bug imho:
https://bitbucket.org/whosaysni/elaphe/commits/19dd8f58c76ac75914e3e4d8ae7db1b9489cbcb8?at=develop

This patch is from the 2014-10-22, the current version elaphe 0.6.0 on pypi is from 2013-12-05. If you installed via pip you have the buggy version.

There is a python3 enabled fork of this project https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elaphe3, which was uploaded on the 2016-05-25. So this fork might contain the necessary bugfix. You could remove elaphe and install elaphe3.

However, considering that elaphe (at least the non 3 version) looks pretty abandoned and has GhostScript and PIL as dependencies I would look for another solution.

Comment: Thanks much for the research and the explanation! I looked and found zint, which does everything I need. I'll just have to run it as a shell command.